# Continuity Proof

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $c$ and $f(c)<g(c)$. I seek to prove that there exists a neighborhood $I$ of $c$ such that $f(x)<g(x)$ for $x \in I$.

It seems to make sense to me, but I'm not sure how to formalize a proof.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $f(g) = g(c)$??

Comment: whoops!, my apologies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$t(x)=f(x)-g(x)$$
$$t(c)<0$$
By continuity of $t(x)$ .For every $\epsilon >0$ here exist a $\delta >0$ such that
$$|t(x)-t(c)|<\epsilon$$ 
there exist a $\delta >0$ such that $|x-c|<\delta$

Let $\large \epsilon = -\frac{t(c)}{2}$(Remember $t(c)$ is negative)
Then as $|t(x)-t(c)|<-\frac{t(c)}{2}$
we have $\large \frac{3t(c)}{2}<t(x)<\frac{t(c)}{2}$ which means that $t(x)$ is negative in some neigbourhood of it.
$$\Large t(x)<0 \Rightarrow f(x)<g(x)$$ Q.E.D

---

Actually $t(x)$ has a neighbourhood in which it's sign is negative follows by "sign preserving property of continuous function". But as the OP insisted on a formal proof I wrote a proof which is actually the proof of "sign preserving property of continuous function".